# Route is not matched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I can't figure out why this is not matching my route for the `CompanyDetailContainer`.  The route for Interview container works fine

```
      <IndexRoute component={HomePageContainer} />
      <Route component={InterviewContainer} name="interview" path="interviews/companies/:companyId" />
      <Route component={CompanyDetailContainer} name="companydetail" path="interviews/companies/:companyId/details" />
```

so `http://localhost:8080/interviews/companies/10` hits the `interview` route fine but `http://localhost:8080/interviews/companies/501/details` does not hit the `companydetail` route

**UPDATE**:

I'm using:

```
"react-router": "^3.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
```

original code:

```
import { IndexRoute, Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

  <Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={onUpdate}>
    <Route path="/">
      <IndexRoute component={HomePageContainer} />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact component={InterviewContainer} name="interview" path="interviews/companies/:companyId" />
        <Route exact component={CompanyDetailContainer} name="companydetail" path="interviews/companies/:companyId/details" />
      </Switch>
      <Route component={About} name="about" path="about"  />
      <Route component={JobList} name="jobs" path="jobs"  />
    </Route>
    <Route component={Container} path="/"  />
    <Route component={NotFound} path="*"  />
  </Router>
```

adding just exact to what I had didn't work:

```
import { IndexRoute, Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';


  <Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={onUpdate}>
      <Route path="/" component={HomePageContainer}>
        <Route component={InterviewContainer} exact name="interview" path="interviews/companies/:companyId" />
        <Route component={CompanyDetailContainer} exact name="companydetail" path="interviews/companies/:companyId/details" />
        <Route component={About} name="about" path="about" />
        <Route component={JobList} name="jobs" path="jobs" />
        <Route component={Container} path="/"  />
        <Route component={NotFound} path="*"  />
      </Route>

  </Router>
```

Then I tried to add switch around it:

```
import { Router, Route, Switch, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

  <Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={onUpdate}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={HomePageContainer}>
        <Route component={InterviewContainer} exact name="interview" path="interviews/companies/:companyId" />
        <Route component={CompanyDetailContainer} exact name="companydetail" path="interviews/companies/:companyId/details" />
        <Route component={About} name="about" path="about" />
        <Route component={JobList} name="jobs" path="jobs" />
        <Route component={Container} path="/"  />
        <Route component={NotFound} path="*"  />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

And now I get this error: `Cannot read property 'createRouteFromReactElement' of undefined`.  I noticed my import for `Switch` is not resolving but that's how you import `Switch` right?

Also not sure if all those routes should be sub routes of `<Route path="/" component={HomePageContainer}>`?  Note that I removed the `<IndexRoute />` per suggestions too.

Comment: Try adding the "exact" prop to the interview route, otherwise it will always match first, before the details route path is evaluated

Comment: Looks like you are using some version of RR before v4... when posting questions, try to specify the version, especially in case of React Router.

Comment: Looking at the version info, I think that you are doing a mistake by importing different versions of `react-router` and `react-router-dom`. See this thread: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4648#issuecomment-284479720  **Long story short, you only need to import `react-router-dom`, not both**

Comment: All:  have not had a chance to try more.  Will be back soon to report my progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router V4 is split out into two packages. One for Web (DOM) and one for Native.

Therefore, you don’t need the **react-router** dependency, just **react-router-dom**.

So import the components from **react-router-dom** instead:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
```

You can then wrap your routes in a **Switch** so that only one route is matched.

If you put your **details** route above the other then it should match first:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePageContainer} />
    <Route path="/interviews/companies/:companyId/details" component={CompanyDetailContainer} />
    <Route path="/interviews/companies/:companyId" component={InterviewContainer} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/jobs" component={JobList} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Also note that with React Router V4, you don’t nest routes. Instead you can add additional routes within your components.

Comment: one problem is the '/' works but all other routes when hit, bring me to a blank page.  I've created a new stack post on that issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47301303/route-redirects-to-nothing-react-router-4

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the two routes with a wrapping with Switch :

```
import {Switch} from 'react-router';

<IndexRoute component={HomePageContainer} />
<Switch>
  <Route component={CompanyDetailContainer} name="companydetail" path="interviews/companies/:companyId/details" />
  <Route component={InterviewContainer} name="interview" path="interviews/companies/:companyId" />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Use a [`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch), which is used to *exclusively* render just one route.
2. Use the [`exact`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) prop of the `Route` component, which renders the component only if the path is an exact match.

Eg:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact component={InterviewContainer} name="interview" path="interviews/companies/:companyId" />
  <Route exact component={CompanyDetailContainer} name="companydetail" path="interviews/companies/:companyId/details" />
</Switch>
```

**P.S.** I think you wouldn't need `IndexedRoute` when using `Switch` ( but you better check it in the docs of the version you are using)

Comment: have not had a chance to revisit today, probably tomorrow or sometime this week.