# route redirects to nothing react-router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm not sure why everything is redirecting to a blank page:

I'm using:

```
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
```

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

    class Container extends Component{
      render() {
        return (
          <div>{this.props.children}</div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <BrowserRouter onUpdate={onUpdate}>
            <Switch>
              <Route component={HomePageContainer} exact path="/" />
              <Route component={CompanyDetailContainer} name="companydetail" path="interviews/companies/:companyId/details" />
              <Route component={InterviewContainer} name="interview" path="interviews/companies/:companyId" />
              <Route component={Container} path="/" />
              <Route component={NotFound} path="*" />
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        );
      }
    }
```

Homepage route to '/' is working fine.

What's not working are all the other routes.

For example when a user clicks a hyperlink that redirects to these routes or other routes other than the default route, I'm getting a blank page:

```
   <Route component={CompanyDetailContainer} name="companydetail" path="interviews/companies/:companyId/details" />
      <Route component={InterviewContainer} name="interview" path="interviews/companies/:companyId" />
```

Here is how my routes were working when I was using react-router **v3**:

```
<Router history={browserHistory} onUpdate={onUpdate}>
    <Route path="/">
      <IndexRoute component={HomePageContainer} />
      <Route component={InterviewContainer} name="interview"  path="interviews/companies/:companyId" />
      <Route component={About} name="about" path="about"  />
      <Route component={JobList} name="jobs" path="jobs"  />
    </Route>
    <Route component={Container} path="/"  />
    <Route component={NotFound} path="*"  />
</Router>
```

**Note** that I also added the new route for **companydetail** just recently.

Answer (score 0):

All your paths needs to be with respect to to base path i.e. `/`

Change your router config to

```
 <Switch>
          <Route component={HomePageContainer} exact path="/" />
          <Route component={CompanyDetailContainer} name="companydetail" path="/interviews/companies/:companyId/details" />
          <Route component={InterviewContainer} name="interview" path="/interviews/companies/:companyId" />
          <Route component={Container} path="/" />
          <Route component={NotFound} path="*" />
 </Switch>
```

Comment: I don't see what you did differently

Comment: base Paths must have a  leading `/` `path="/interviews/companies/:companyId/details"` and `path="/interviews/companies/:companyId"`

Comment: yea I see it.  So is this a react-router 4 thing?  Because I'm no longer able to nest right?  When in v3 I was nesting, that '/' was taken care of in the parent route probably

Comment: it still doesn't work...

Comment: Check this answer on how to nest routes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452858/how-to-write-nested-routes-in-react-router-v4/44453559#44453559

Comment: I don't get it so I have to also add routes to my CompanyDetailContainer, InterviewContainer, etc.?

Comment: Yes, from v4 onwards you can write your routes in the container itself instead of nesting it at the top level and writing {this.props.children} in the container

Comment: I know, but then why are people saying I should be able to get the above working as is?

Comment: your Container component simply renders this.props.children which will be undefined and maybe your routes are rendering `/`, can you confirm that. Also can you show how are you redirecting. Redirect links should also be wrt base route

Comment: I am using react-router's Link component for redirecting.  `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';`. Then when I click on that, it hits whatever route and showing me a blank page whereas in react v3, I was using link via `const Link = require('react-router').Link;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159033/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-positiveguy).

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your router in an anonymous function.

```
const App = () => (
      <BrowserRouter onUpdate={onUpdate}>
        <Switch>
          <Route component={HomePageContainer} exact path="/" />
          <Route component={CompanyDetailContainer} name="companydetail" path="interviews/companies/:companyId/details" />
          <Route component={InterviewContainer} name="interview" path="interviews/companies/:companyId" />
          <Route component={Container} path="/" />
          <Route component={NotFound} path="*" />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
)
```

Comment: why/??? I like it as a class

Comment: because all of the v4 examples have it that way ><  https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf

Comment: yea but it doesn't have to be that way..

Comment: I was just suggesting you try it and see if you can get something to work like the examples, then alter to taste after you get it working.